# How do I implement Google Play Game services in my app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to figure out exactly how to implement Google Play Game services in my app. On the Google Play Developer Console I've linked the game the relevant app using the SHA1 key and I know how to add leaderboards and achievements on here. I have also installed the Google Play services and Google Repository to Android Studio and added the dependency into `build.gradle` (as explained here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) but I wasn't sure **how to do the last 2 steps on that page (creating a Proguard exception and ensuring devices have the Google Play services APK) and if they are necessary** - the latter of which even the Google Play Games sample projects don't seem to do.

Moreover, **I'm not sure what code I actually need to put in my project to enable leaderboards and achievements**, since according to this guide: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements, I use this code:

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "my_achievement_id");
```

to unlock an achievement, for example, but there are no instructions on how I set up `mGoogleApiClient`. **I've looked at the sample projects but it's still not clear what I'm supposed to do**. Am I meant to copy and paste all of the code into my project? Are there certain sections I'm supposed to copy and paste? Do I have to write my own code for signing in to Google Play Games?

Answer (score 0):

You should use getApiClient() instead of mGoogleApiClient.

Assuming you have an activity with a layout containing four buttons:

```
 Leaderboard button - To launch the leaderboards,
 Achievement button - To launch achievements
 Sign in and Sign out buttons
```

For leaderboard, we push scores for `best minutes, best distance covered and an overall highscore`.

And for achievements, we unlock four achievements - `survivor, warrior, lord, pride` based on certain conditions.

Here's how you'd go about it:

```
public class GMSActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements OnClickListener{
    Button lead;
    Button achv;
    final int RC_RESOLVE = 5000, RC_UNUSED = 5001;
//your game score. so we can push to cloud
    int hS = 0; 
//flags for achievements
   boolean survivor;
   boolean tribalWarriror;
   boolean akonfemLord;
   boolean zuluPride;
   LinearLayout signInBar;
   LinearLayout signOutBar;
    Resources r;
    private float bestTimeInSeconds;
    private int bestTimeInMinutes;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.gms_layout);
            r = getResources();
            lead = (Button)findViewById(R.id.leaderboards);
            achv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.achievements);
            hS = loadScores();
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);


            lead.setOnClickListener(this);
            achv.setOnClickListener(this);


               signInBar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar);
               signOutBar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar);


            checkForAchievements();
             if (isSignedIn()) {
                 onSignInSucceeded();
             }else{
                onSignInFailed();
             }


        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(v == lead){
                  if (isSignedIn()) {
                        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient()), RC_UNUSED);
                    } else {
                        showAlert(getString(R.string.leaderboards_not_available));
                    }
            }else if(v ==achv){
                 if (isSignedIn()) {
                        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), RC_UNUSED);
                    } else {
                        showAlert(getString(R.string.achievements_not_available));
                    }

            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button){
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();

            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button){
                  signOut();
                  hello.setText(getString(R.string.signed_out_greeting));
                    signInBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    signOutBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }



        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed() {
            hello.setText(getString(R.string.signed_out_greeting));
            signInBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            signOutBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded() {

            signInBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            signOutBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             // Set the greeting appropriately on main menu
            Player p = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(getApiClient());
            String displayName;
            if (p == null) {
             //   Log.w(TAG, "mGamesClient.getCurrentPlayer() is NULL!");
                displayName = "";
            } else {
                displayName = p.getDisplayName();
            }
           // hello.setText("Hello, " + displayName);

                pushAccomplishments();
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.your_progress_will_be_uploaded),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        //check for achievements and unlock the appropriate ones
         void checkForAchievements() {
                // Check if each condition is met; if so, unlock the corresponding
                // achievement.
              bestTimeInSeconds = loadGameBestTimeSec();
              if(bestTimeInSeconds >= 900){ //15 minutes
                  survivor = true;
                  tribalWarriror = true;
              }

            }

          void pushAccomplishments() {
              if (survivor) 
                    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.achievement_survivor));

              if (tribalWarriror) 
                    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.achievement_tribal_warrior));


              if(bestTimeInSeconds >= 60){ //1 minute atleast
                     bestTimeInMinutes = (int)bestTimeInSeconds/60;
              Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_best_time_minutes), bestTimeInMinutes);
                }

              if(bestTimeInSeconds >= 10){   // 1 meter atleast
                    int bestDistance = (int)bestTimeInSeconds/10;
              Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_best_distance_meters), bestDistance);
                }


              Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_top_score_points), hS);

            }


             @Override


             //loading scores and achievements
             private int loadScores() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 int score = 0;
                   try{
                    preferences = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext(),
                            "besiPreferences", "1234", true);
                    score = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("highScore"));
                   }catch(Exception e){}
                    return score;

                    }

             private float loadGameBestTimeSec() {
                 float time = 0;
                  try{
                preferences = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext(),
                            "besiPreferences", "1234", true);
                time = Float.parseFloat(preferences.getString("gameTimeSec"));
                  }catch(Exception e){}
                   return time;
             }

             private int loadCalabashesCompleted() {
                    try{
                        preferences = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext(),
                                "makolaPref", "1234", true);
                        return Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("bookCompleted")== null ? "0" : preferences.getString("bookCompleted"));
                       }catch(Exception e){
                         return 0;  
                       }
                }

             private int loadLevelCompleted() {
                    try{
                        preferences = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext(),
                                "makolaPref", "1234", true);
                        return Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("levelCompleted")== null ? "0" : preferences.getString("levelCompleted"));
                       }catch(Exception e){
                         return 0;  
                       }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, sort of makes sense, is there any other code I need, like BaseGameUtils? And would I need to check the device has the Google Play Game services installed, etc.?

Comment: Yes, you need the BaseGameUitls library- https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/   And no, you don't need to check if the device has the google play game services installed